# Positive LookBehind for Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Could use some help here. I have dug around and having trouble locating a string due to the special characters I have to pass through.

Trying to capture any number that would be where the "258" is the following string:
"**.value), 258, '0')**"

The below is what I am looking for as the string I want to capture can be many digits longs and only digits 0-9.

```
(?<=value\), )(.*)(?=\,)
```

Any alternatives would be helpful as Positive LookBehind for Javascript is not supported any longer  :(

Comment: Can you point me to a source for the fact that positive lookbehinds aren't supported? Anyway, try using capture groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capturing groups and then extract the one that has 258 in it like so:

```js
let regex = /(value\), )(\d*)/;
let string = ".value), 258, '0')";
let output = regex.exec(string);
console.log(output[2])

//output[0] is the whole match
//output[1] is the first capture group: "value), "
//output[2] is the second capture group: "258"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = ".value), 258, '0')"
match = /value\), (\d+),/.exec(str)

if (match) console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match .value),  with `\.value\),` and then capture one or more digits in a capturing group with `(\d+)`.

This will be the first capturing group and in the example will be `matches[1]`

If this must be followed by a comma, you could use a positive lookahead `(?=,)` *(You don't have to escape the comma)* or instead of the lookahead match what comes after the captured group like `,` or `, '0'\)`

[`\.value\), (\d+)(?=,)`](https://regex101.com/r/sKfyXv/1/)

**For example:**

```js
var pattern = /\.value\), (\d+)(?=,)/;
var str = ".value), 258, '0')";
matches = str.match(pattern);
console.log(matches[1]);
```